# Get data from array base on a value in this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array:

```
$fruits = array(
    array(
        'fruit'       => "Banana", 
        'color'       => "Yellow",
        'latinName'   => "Banana",
        'origin'      => "Africa"
    ),
);
```

How can I get the `color` if I have the `fruit` value for example ?

**I'm using this structure as I would like to use this array, by giving the `fruit name`, the `color` or the `latinName` to get other informations.**

Thanks.

Comment: I would rearrange your array so the array with the fruit's data in is an array of the top level array, with the key being the fruit name. eg `array ( banana => array (color => "pink", "latinname" => "Banaerous Athra") )`. (although not sure a banana will have a latin name...). As it is now, you;d have to walk through the array, find the sub array which contains the fruit you are referencing, and then lookup the colour within that array.

Comment: Good point but I built it like this in order to use the same array to get value based on different datas (fruits, color, latinName or origin). With you solution, I will need an array for each datas.

Comment: How do you NOT need an array for each data with *your* solution? If you have just one array, no sub level arrays, how can you distinguish which colour goes with which fruit, especially given you cannot have dupe key names.

Comment: I would like to use this array, by giving the fruit name, the color or the latinName.

Comment: Considering this, perhaps you can propose me a new structure ?

Comment: @Bonito There is nothing wrong with the structure, it is replicating a row of data from a database quite well. I would try to let the database do the matching if you start getting into large numbers of fruits to match though. The answer I posted also gives you exactly what you want :)

Comment: It's not from a db. Just an array tonstore my datas. So if it's not the structure what the problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem like I said. One subarray for each value, seems clean and simple enough. I am adding an edit to my answer on the structure for you though.

Comment: Using auto numerical arrays isn't the best option here, associative arrays would be easier as they'd allow for a logical index on each sub array, thus more easy to locate the required data within a likely given scenario, as per your question here! So your fruit name being the sub array index (key), and the data within each sub array would be the data relating to the index. Look at Coletz95's answer which extends how you are doing it. How do you find data on banana? You first have to find which sub array banana is in, then get data from within the sub array referencing your previous search.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the best way, but it works for sure (maybe there's some function too, but idk sorry):

```
$fruits = array(
    array(
        "fruit"         => "Banana", 
        "color"         => "Yellow",
        "latinName"     => "Banana",
        "origin"        => "Africa"
    ),
    array(
        "fruit"         => "Apple", 
        "color"         => "Red",
        "latinName"     => "Dunno1",
        "origin"        => "Dunno2"
    ),
    array(
        "fruit"         => "Orange", 
        "color"         => "Orange",
        "latinName"     => "Dunno3",
        "origin"        => "Dunno4"
    ),
);

for($i=0; $i<count($fruits); $i++){
    if($fruits[$i]["fruit"]=="Banana"){
        echo $fruits[$i]["color"];
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed quotes around the key names is what was meant.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `array_flip` in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). While I would agree that your data structure makes this rather awkward, this function might alleviate some of the issues.

Comment: Agreed - the structure is odd but I was thinking more in terms of the original question 'how to find color if you have the fruit'

Answer (score 0):

Seems a pretty trivial foreach statement unless I missed something rather glaringly obvious:

```
<?php 

    $input='Banana';
    $fruits = array(
        array(
        'fruit'         => "Banana", 
        'color'         => "Yellow",
        'latinName'     => "Banana",
        'origin'        => "Africa"
        ),
    );

    foreach($fruits as $val)
    {
        if($val['fruit']==$input)
        {
            echo $val['color'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Edit: On the structure of your array, there is nothing wrong with this simple 2d array. If anything, I would consider using a key naming structure for your outer array which might make it easier to use for you:

```
$fruits = array(
    "Banana" => 
            array(
            'color'         => "Yellow",
            'latinName'     => "Banana",
            'origin'        => "Africa"
    )
);
```

This way you can then use the common name to access the right inner array - and you get to use all the inbuilt PHP functions for finding/accessing keys as needed.

Comment: Hi @James, if there are missing quotes in an answer, there is nothing wrong with suggesting an edit to improve it rather than leaving snarky comments - in fact it will contribute to the site in a meaningful way. Wait till your rep gets higher to play the snarky comment game :)

Comment: Which one of the following comments do you think adds more value to the site: "Your code will output at least 4 errors." or "You forgot to add quotes to the copied code in the array keys." Just saying, it's a great thing to be positive rather than negative :)

Comment: What I said was neither snarky nor negative, it was an informative, to the point, friendly nudge that you made a mistake. Firstly, it's up to you to provide working code, not others to make sure you've done it right. I could have justifiably downvoted as your code had errors, as many do. But instead I didn't downvote and gave you a *friendly nudge*! Apparently that isn't good enough and I should have written out where you went wrong? As you said, I'll wait until my rep is higher, I presume I'll be cleverer then..

Comment: @James Okay, okay. I might have used "snarky" a little too harshly - and it appears you are still miffed about it a half hour later. I apologise for that. Yes, I missed quotes in the copied snippet, yes, there were errors. But a typo is a typo - we all make them and there are helpful ways to point them out. In about 600 rep you will be able to simple edit and correct questions/answers. I hope you would use that priv to do so to make the site a better place for all.

Comment: I apologized as I thought it was the right thing to do. I don't want comments that I make to discourage people from contributing in a positive way to the site in any way, shape of form. Anyhow, lets move on and go help some people with their questions :)